# Having problems getting getting Razor to see my CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to get my labels and text boxes to line up and I'm not getting it work right.

Here is what I have:

AddCustomer.cshtml

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.Models.AddCustomerModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Add an Existing Account";
}

<h2>Change Password</h2>
<p>
    Use the form below to add an existing account to your web login. 
</p>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account not found. Please verify the infomartion below and try again.")




  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Account Information</legend>

      <p>
         <span class="smalllabel">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Branch)
         </span>

         <span class="largelabel">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountNumber)
         </span>

      <br />

         <span class="smalltextbox">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Branch)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Branch) 
         </span>

         <span class="largetextbox">        
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccountNumber) 
         </span>
      </p>

      <div class="editor-label">
        AND
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
        OR
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
      </div>


      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
      </p>

    </fieldset>
  </div>
}
```

This is my Site.css:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------
The base color for this template is #5c87b2. If you'd like
to use a different color start by replacing all instances of
#5c87b2 with your new color.
----------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
    background-color: #5c87b2;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #696969;
}

a:link {
    color: #034af3;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    color: #505abc;
}

a:hover {
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    color: #12eb87;
}

p, ul {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

header,
footer,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}

/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* you can specify a greater or lesser percentage for the 
page width. Or, you can specify an exact pixel width. */
.page {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

header, #header {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0;
}

header h1, #header h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 32px !important;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #111;
}

#main {
    padding: 30px 30px 15px 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}

footer, 
#footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #999;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#menu li#greeting {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    color: #fff;
}

ul#menu li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    background-color: #e8eef4;
    color: #034af3;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:active {
    background-color: #a6e2a6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li.selected a {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

/* FORM LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}

legend {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

textarea {
    min-height: 75px;
}

input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #444;
    width: 200px;
}

select {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #444;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 5px;
}

/* TABLE
----------------------------------------------------------*/

table {
    border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
}

table th {
    padding: 6px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #e8eef4;
    border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.error {
    color: Red;
}

nav, 
#menucontainer {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

div#title {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

#logindisplay {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px;
    color: White;
}

#logindisplay a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#logindisplay a:visited {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#logindisplay a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

/* Styles for editor and display helpers
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.display-label, 
.editor-label {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.display-field, 
.editor-field {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}

.text-box {
    width: 30em;
}

.text-box.multi-line {
    height: 6.5em;
}

.tri-state {
    width: 6em;
}

/* custom created by eric */

.smalllabel {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    width: 30em;
}

.smalltextbox {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    width: 30em;
}

.largelabel {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    width: 60em;
}

.largetextbox {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    width: 60em;
}
```

And this is the results:

[image]

I am trying to get the Branch label and text box to be the same small size and the account number to be the larger (same) size.

Apparently I'm not getting the css classes right in the code.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using -

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Branch, new { @class = "smalltextbox" })
```

this will apply the class to the textbox directly and not the span wrapper - I think you are using the default css file with a razor page that contains a css class that is applying to your textbox while you are applying your css to the span wrapper.

Also, smalltextbox and smalllabel look the same to me :) - not sure if you need them both.

Comment: I added this and got an error:  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Branch, new { class = "smalllabel" })   Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected
 on this line.  Where is the } missing at?

Comment: oops - sorry - make it 
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Branch, new { @class = "smalllabel" })

I forgot the @ is necessary here.

Comment: sorry to be a bother but I made that change and it gives this:

Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<SuburbanCustPortal.Models.AddCustomerModel>' does not contain a definition for 'LabelFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>, string)' has some invalid arguments
Any ideas?

Comment: I know I put LabelFor - but I think you really wanted TextBoxFor - is that it.  I tried doing the samething in a test and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make smalltextbox and small label float: left.

Comment: what does that have to do with the size of my textbox?

Comment: Well, you are assigning the css to spans, and width won't work on them unless they float. If the size of the textbox is an issue, you can give textboxfor a second argument with html attributes, like "Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myField, { width = 30px } )", or something like that.