# Styling Not Displaying As I Intended

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

From [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519393/having-problems-getting-getting-razor-to-see-my-css) I have this code:

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.Models.AddCustomerModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Add an Existing Account";
}

<h2>Add an existing account.</h2>
<p>
    Use the form below to add an existing account to your web login. 
</p>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account not found. Please verify the infomartion below and try again.")

  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Account Information</legend>

      <div>
        <label class="small-label">Branch</label><label class="large-label">Account Number</label>      
      </div>

      <br />

      <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Branch, new { @class = "small-textbox" }) 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountNumber, new { @class = "large-textbox" })
      </div>

      <div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Branch) 
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccountNumber) 
      </div>

      <br />     
      <br />
      <br />

      <fieldset>
        <legend>AND</legend>

          <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
          </div>
          <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
          </div>

          <br />

          <label class="excited-label">- OR -</label>

          <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
          </div>
          <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
          </div>

      </fieldset>

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
      </p>

    </fieldset>
  </div>
}
```

Any my css:

```
body {
    background-color: #5c87b2;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #696969;
}

a:link {
    color: #034af3;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    color: #505abc;
}

a:hover {
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    color: #12eb87;
}

p, ul {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

header,
footer,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}

/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* you can specify a greater or lesser percentage for the 
page width. Or, you can specify an exact pixel width. */
.page {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

header, #header {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0;
}

header h1, #header h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 32px !important;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #111;
}

#main {
    padding: 30px 30px 15px 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}

footer, 
#footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #999;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#menu li#greeting {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    color: #fff;
}

ul#menu li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    background-color: #e8eef4;
    color: #034af3;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:active {
    background-color: #a6e2a6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li.selected a {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

/* FORM LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}

legend {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

textarea {
    min-height: 75px;
}

input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #444;
    width: 200px;
}

select {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #444;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 5px;
}

/* TABLE
----------------------------------------------------------*/

table {
    border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
}

table th {
    padding: 6px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #e8eef4;
    border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.error {
    color: Red;
}

nav, 
#menucontainer {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

div#title {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

#logindisplay {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px;
    color: White;
}

#logindisplay a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#logindisplay a:visited {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#logindisplay a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

/* Styles for editor and display helpers
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.display-label, 
.editor-label {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.display-field, 
.editor-field {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}

.text-box {
    width: 30em;
}

.text-box.multi-line {
    height: 6.5em;
}

.tri-state {
    width: 6em;
}

/* custom created by eric */

.small-label 
{
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.small-textbox 
{
  float: left;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  width: 50px;
}

.large-label 
{
  float: left;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  width: 150px;
}

.large-textbox 
{
  float: left;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  width: 150px;
}

.excited-label{
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: blue;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

The css for these lines is not working correctly:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Branch, new { @class = "small-textbox" }) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountNumber, new { @class = "large-textbox" })
```

It is not applying the small-textbox or large-textbox.

And it is also displaying all on one line even though I use < div> or < p>.

Here is what it is showing:

[image]

Anyone have any ideas why my form is displaying oddly?

Comment: With Tim B James' help below and this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820586/how-can-i-control-the-width-of-a-label-tag I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Css for those elements is working correctly. They are both floating left, which means that unless they run out of space within their containing element, then they will float next to each other.

If you want them to break onto a new line, then you need to apply the style `clear: left;` or `clear: both;`

e.g.

```
.large-textbox 
{
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: k I understand, any idea why the width part isn't working? I didn't clarify that part I know. I will update my post.

Comment: Your input widths are not working as you would expect because you are setting the width of `input[type="text"]` to `200px`. So either remove this, or set it to `input.small-textbox{ width... }`

Comment: I apologize for not getting this part, but I added this line towards the end input.small-textbox { width: 50; } and it didn't make any changes to the textbox.

Comment: If you open the website in Google Chrome, right click on the input and select "Inspect element" from the menu, you will be able to see how the css is being applied, and what is causing the issue.